# In Angular, should injected global services be private or public? Is there a performance hit one way or the other?

Tags: angular

Nothing too complicated here, just a team member who suggests that performance is better when injected global services are made public rather than private in the components they are injected into.

Comment: No it's not. [private and public properties don't exist in JS](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20prop1%3A%20string%20%3D%20'prop1'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop2%3A%20string%20%3D%20'prop2'%3B%0D%0A%7D), it won't change a thing.

Comment: they are both compile-time only construct. check this out for a detailed answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37506946/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is zero performance impact. Remember that Typescript is compiled down to Javascript at the end of the day.

You can try the following:

1. Compile your project using ng build --prod
2. Add the contents of your output directory to git version control
3. Change the dependency injection to public
4. Compile again and check git status

You will notice that there is **absolutely no difference** in the compiled Javascript.

Generally speaking, services should be injected as private. You'd only mark them as public if you want to access the service directly from the template, which leans towards bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing too complicated here, just a team member who suggests that performance is better when injected global services are made public rather than private in the components they are injected into.

He might be referring to boxing of a variable to make it private. Where the definition of a class prototype is wrapped in the context of a function, and private variables are localized to that context.

For example; (note, this doesn't handle multiple Car instances)

```
 const Car = (function() {
    let _wheels = 0;
    function Car(wheels) {
      _wheels = wheels;
    }
    Car.prototype.wheels = function() {
       return _wheels;
    };
    return Car;
}());
```

In Angular, we use TypeScript to generate the class prototypes and TypeScript does not implement boxing of private members.

If you use boxing of private properties, then you can not clone objects using deconstruction or `Object.assign()`.

```
 let a = {_x:'hello'};
 let b = {...a};
 console.log(b._x); // prints "hello"
```

The above wouldn't work if `_x` was a hidden private property.

Example;

```
class Person {
    constructor(private name:string) {}
}
```

Is compiled from TypeScript into JavaScript as follows:

```
var Person = (function() {
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

TypeScript still generates a function context, but does not make private properties hidden.

Reference: https://yakovfain.com/2015/06/30/the-private-in-typescript-is-kinda-private/

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it helped a lot. Sorry I didn't choose it as the "selected answer"!